# Can we get google-map launched time in android?

Tags: android, time, google-maps-api-3

I want to take time stamp in my application, when user launches google-map or google-map launched by other applications in android. Is there any android API to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, no, as this would be a privacy violation.

Comment: Thank you, i need some more info, can we take time stamp when user explicitly inputs location detail to google-map?

Comment: @Vani: Fortunately, no, as this would be a privacy violation.

Comment: Thank you, I am referring your books